# Why can't my Set remove duplicate elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
let arr = new Set();
arr.add([1,1,1,1]);
arr.add([1,1,1,1]);
console.log(arr);
```

1. Why output is [[1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1]] ?
2. If I want to remove duplicate elements, I should taking something?
   (I want to making [[1,1,1,1]])

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: @Andy He probably wants this output: Set(1) { [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ] }

Comment: Note also that those arrays are invalid syntax.

Comment: It's why I asked. The OP might just have wanted `[1]`.

Comment: Yeah, he didn't place the comma, event though he adds, the output will remain the same

Comment: I am so sorry that my code has semantic error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object references are different. Similar to how `{}=={}` returns false.

You can use JSON.stringify() to get past this:

```js
console.log([1,1,1,1,] === [1,1,1,1]);

let arr = new Set();
arr.add([1,1,1,1]);
arr.add([1,1,1,1]);

let ans = new Set([...arr].map(x => JSON.stringify(x)));
```

Now `ans` is a Set that contains only one element `[1,1,1,1]`.

Comment: This is very useful advice. Thank you very much~

Answer (score 1):

this will be helpful to revert back as array items was before

```
Array.from(new Set([[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]].map(JSON.stringify)), JSON.parse);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you add an array inside your set, SET does not deep compare your element and [1, 1] !== [1, 1] because they share a different reference.

I think you wanted to do

```js
arr = new Set();
arr.add(...[1, 1, 1, 1]);
arr.add(...[1, 1, 1, 1]);
console.log(arr);
```